# I found this error in logcat hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, mobile

I run my App on my phone. Everything works perfectly.. But after i check in my logcat for the debug.
It's show me this error.

> E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
>   E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc

It's show when user run the app for the first time. It's show just in time the app show splash screen. I'm not sure which code that make this thing happen. 
So i'll show you my splash code and my fragment home code.

so this is my splasactivity code :

```
package com.apps.mathar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.apps.utils.Constant;
import com.apps.utils.JsonUtils;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

//        hideStatusBar();
        setStatusColor();

        try {
           Constant.isFromPush = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("ispushnoti", false);
           Constant.pushID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("noti_nid");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Constant.isFromPush = false;
        }
        try {
            Constant.isFromNoti = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isnoti", false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Constant.isFromNoti = false;
        }

        JsonUtils jsonUtils = new JsonUtils(SplashActivity.this);

        Resources r = getResources();
        float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Constant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        Constant.columnWidth = (int) ((jsonUtils.getScreenWidth() - ((Constant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / Constant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

        if(!Constant.isFromNoti) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    openMainActivity();
                }
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            openMainActivity();
        }
    }

    private void openMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void setStatusColor()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBar));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my fragmenthome code

```
    package com.apps.mathar;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
        import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.apps.adapter.AdapterRecent;
        import com.apps.item.ItemSong;
        import com.apps.utils.Constant;
        import com.apps.utils.DBHelper;
        import com.apps.utils.JsonUtils;
        import com.apps.utils.RecyclerItemClickListener;
        import com.apps.utils.ZProgressHUD;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
        import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ItemSong> arrayList;
    ArrayList<ItemSong> arrayList_recent;
    AdapterRecent adapterRecent;
    ZProgressHUD progressHUD;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    public ViewPager viewpager;
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter;
    TextView textView_empty;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());

        progressHUD = ZProgressHUD.getInstance(getActivity());
        progressHUD.setMessage(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progressHUD.setSpinnerType(ZProgressHUD.FADED_ROUND_SPINNER);

        textView_empty = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_recent_empty);

        adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewpager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_home);
        viewpager.setPadding(80,20,80,20);
        viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewpager.setPageMargin(40);
        viewpager.setClipChildren(false);
//        viewpager.setPageTransformer(true,new BackgroundToForegroundTransformer());

        arrayList = new ArrayList<ItemSong>();
        arrayList_recent = new ArrayList<ItemSong>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_home_recent);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            new LoadLatestNews().execute(Constant.URL_LATEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if(JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                    Constant.isOnline = true;
                    Constant.arrayList_play.clear();
                    Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList_recent);
                    Constant.playPos = position;
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList_recent.get(position).getMp3Name(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getCategoryName(),position+1,arrayList_recent.size(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getDuration(),arrayList_recent.get(position).getImageBig(),"home");

                    Constant.context = getActivity();
                    if(position == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
                        intent.setAction(PlayerService.ACTION_FIRST_PLAY);
                        getActivity().startService(intent);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }));

        return rootView;
    }

    private class LoadLatestNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressHUD.show();
            arrayList.clear();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                String json = JsonUtils.getJSONString(strings[0]);

                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.TAG_ROOT);
                JSONObject objJson = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_ID);
                    String cid = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_CAT_ID);
                    String cname = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_CAT_NAME);
                    String artist = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_ARTIST);
                    String name = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_SONG_NAME);
                    String url = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_MP3_URL);
                    String desc = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_DESC);
                    String duration = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_DURATION);
                    String image = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_THUMB_B).replace(" ","%20");
                    String image_small = objJson.getString(Constant.TAG_THUMB_S).replace(" ","%20");

                    ItemSong objItem = new ItemSong(id,cid,cname,artist,url,image,image_small,name,duration,desc);
                    arrayList.add(objItem);
                }

                return "1";
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "0";
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
                return "0";
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent);
            if(s.equals("1")) {
                progressHUD.dismissWithSuccess(getResources().getString(R.string.success));
//                setLatestVariables(0);

                if(Constant.isAppFirst) {
                    if(arrayList.size()>0) {
                        Constant.isAppFirst = false;
                        Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList);
                        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList.get(0).getMp3Name(),arrayList.get(0).getCategoryName(),1,arrayList.size(),arrayList.get(0).getDuration(),arrayList.get(0).getImageBig(),"home");
                        Constant.context = getActivity();
                    }
                }

                viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

                loadRecent();
//                adapterPagerTrending = new AdapterPagerTrending(getActivity(),Constant.arrayList_trending);
//                viewPager_trending.setAdapter(adapterPagerTrending);

//                adapterTopStories = new AdapterTopStories(getActivity(),Constant.arrayList_topstories);
//                listView_topstories.setAdapter(adapterTopStories);

//                setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView_topstories);
                adapterRecent.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                progressHUD.dismissWithFailure(getResources().getString(R.string.error));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.server_no_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent);
        }
    }


    private void loadRecent() {
        arrayList_recent = dbHelper.loadDataRecent();
        adapterRecent = new AdapterRecent(getActivity(),arrayList_recent);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecent);

        if(arrayList_recent.size() == 0) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textView_empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView_empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ImagePagerAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_home, container, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView_pager_home);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading_home);
            TextView title = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_pager_home_title);
            TextView cat = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView_pager_home_cat);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.rl_homepager);

            title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getMp3Name());
            cat.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCategoryName());

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(arrayList.get(position).getImageBig())
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

            rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                        //showInter();
                        playIntent();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.internet_not_conn), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }

    /*    private void showInter() {
            Constant.adCount = Constant.adCount + 1;
            if(Constant.adCount % Constant.adDisplay == 0) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        playIntent();
                        super.onAdClosed();
                    }
                });
                if(((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mInterstitial.show();
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadInter();
                } else {
                    playIntent();
                }
            } else {
                playIntent();
            }
        }
    */
    private void playIntent() {
        Constant.isOnline = true;
        int pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
        Constant.arrayList_play.clear();
        Constant.arrayList_play.addAll(arrayList);
        Constant.playPos = pos;
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeText(arrayList.get(pos).getMp3Name(),arrayList.get(pos).getCategoryName(),pos+1,arrayList.size(),arrayList.get(pos).getDuration(),arrayList.get(pos).getImageBig(),"home");

        Constant.context = getActivity();
        if(pos == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerService.class);
            intent.setAction(PlayerService.ACTION_FIRST_PLAY);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Once more, i'm sure what's going on here.

I'm looking this error since 3 days ago but i have checked my code, i dont know what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error occurs when you have  a loop that doesn't terminate.I also faced the similar kind of situation and It took me literally two days to find out the root cause of problem.

My problem was:

[image]

When I run the above code, I used to get this kind of error 
**hw_get module_by class** **_gralloc...** .

I was really frustrated because I was not able to find out the root cause and luckily I found out that the above section of the code was the main cause because the loop never goes to terminate in the above section and when I found about the problem main cause I replaced it by:

[image]

Then, the problem was solved..
*So maybe your problem lies within the loop or similar kind of  situations..*